# Error parsing XML data to Multi dimensional array

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, arrays, flash-cs3

i'm still transitioning from as2 to as3, i'm having trouble with parsing XML data to Multi dimensional array, below is the onComplete handler which is succesfully tracing 'event.target.data' but outputs 'A term is undefined and has no properties' when tracing _vein_data[0][0].xPos . I'm guessing there is a easier way to approach it than this attempt

```
private function on_xml_completed(event:Event):void {
   var XMLPoints:XML = new XML(event.target.data);

   for ( var i:int = 0; i < XMLPoints.shape.length(); i++ )
    {
     var shapeArray:Array = new Array();
 _vein_data.push(shapeArray);

    for ( var j:int = 0; j < 4; i++ )
    {
  _vein_data[i].push({'xPos':XMLPoints.shape[i].point[j].@xPos,
          'yPos':XMLPoints.shape[i].point[j].@yPos});
 }
}


 trace(_vein_data[0][0].xPos)
   loadAsset();
  }
```

here's a portion of my XML;

```
<items>
 <shape>
  <point xPos="60" yPos="23" />
  <point xPos="65" yPos="23" />
  <point xPos="93" yPos="85" />
  <point xPos="88" yPos="87" />
 </shape>
 <shape>
  <point xPos="88" yPos="87" />
  <point xPos="92" yPos="83" />
  <point xPos="145" yPos="174" />
  <point xPos="138" yPos="175" />
 </shape>
 <shape>
  <point xPos="138" yPos="175" />
  <point xPos="143" yPos="171" />
  <point xPos="147" yPos="211" />
  <point xPos="141" yPos="212" />
 </shape>
</items>
```

thank you in advance for any guidance on this 
Cam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok resolved, 
the problem was the incremented i on the nested for loop, instead of j++;

my bad.